# What does "24Hrs Is A Must" Mean on a Real Estate Listing?

Tags: real-estate

I recently read the following real estate listing:

Beautiful Improved Home Comes Finished With Basement Apartment And Separate Entrance. Upgrades Include Granite, New Shutters, And Parquet Floor Throughout. *Property Is Tenanted - 24Hrs Is A Must*

What does the last line, *Property Is Tenanted - 24Hrs Is A Must*, mean in this context?

Comment: Note that this listing, even just the line you're asking about, can be searched to find the actual address. Consider rewording it if that could be a concern.

Comment: @Lilienthal Thanks, changed it for goodm easure, although I suppose at worst it would have helped sell the house

Comment: I can't imagine that the seller would object if someone drove extra traffic to their advertisement.

Comment: @itcouldevenbeaboat I assumed you asked out of interest but you probably wouldn't want your address or rough geographical location associated with your online handle if it was a property you were thinking of buying. Note though that the last line is still specific enough to be found on Google so you'd have to reword that as well if you're worried but I'm aware that this is sounding more and more paranoid. :]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Given the context, I'd imagine you need to give at least 24 hours notice of viewings so that the landlord can inform the tenant (probably due to a clause in the lease)

Comment: Oh yes! That explains it